# Python Pandas pivot tables format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have made a pivot table using this

```py
piv_full = pd.pivot_table(full_stock_list, index='Unique_Location', values=['StockID', 'SoldStatus'],
                          columns='date_of_file', aggfunc={'StockID': lambda x: len(x.unique()), 'SoldStatus': np.sum})
```

The output looks something like this:

[image: Pivot table output]

Is it possible to make it look something like this:

[image: Pivot table I want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work with some dummy data that mirrored your own:

```
piv_full.stack(level=0)
```